# Blackjack software for Linux/Unix

Tags: linux, game

Anyone know of a decent blackjack software running under Linux/Unix?

The last one I could find was part of gnome-games, but it has been removed from the package for a few years now.

Comment: Your question is lacking details.  For example, what do you consider to be "decent" software?  Please consider editing your question and providing details that would make it easier to answer.

Comment: Sorry I meant any kind of blackjack game that runs under linux specifically as I havent found any so far. Just looking for basic strategy training.

Comment: Basic strategy consists of memorizing a table. There is nothing complicated about it

Comment: Similar question on Ask Ubuntu: [Blackjack game for Linux or Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163127/blackjack-game-for-linux-or-wine)

Answer (score 1):

To get that original Linux Blackjack game, go here - https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/i386/gnome-blackjack/1:2.28.0-0ubuntu1

You'll probably need to download a couple of dependecies as well, but you'll find their links on that page as well.

I quite like that version. :-)

Answer (score 1):

https://gitlab.com/christosangel/blackjack

This is a blackjack game that I myself wrote in javascript.

To install and play it, you just follow the instructions.

I hope you like it, any feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In FreeBSD, there's [blackjackclient](https://www.freshports.org/games/blackjackclient/) (`pkg install blackjackclient`) and [xblackjack](https://www.freshports.org/games/xblackjack/) (`pkg install xblackjack`).